# Question to the python class MemoryClass - just to understand how to build it

Tags: python

I am doing this tutorial from python object programming and I am not sure of two things.
I have built such MemoryClass:

```py
import random

class MemoryClass:
    list_of_already_selected_items = []

    def __init__(self, function):  <-----
        print(">> this is an init of MemoryClass")
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, list):   <-----
        print(">> this is a call of MemoryClass Instance")
        items_not_selected = [i for i in list if i not in MemoryClass.list_of_already_selected_items ]  
        print("---- selecting only from the list of: ", items_not_selected)
        item = self.function(items_not_selected)
        MemoryClass.list_of_already_selected_items.append(item)
        return item

cars = ["Opel", "Toyota", "Fiat", "Ford", "Renault", "Mercedes", "BMV", "Peugot", "Porsche", "Audi", "VW", "Mazda"]

@MemoryClass
def SelectTodaysPromotion(list_of_cars):
    return random.choice(list_of_cars)

@MemoryClass
def SelectTodaysShow(list_of_cars):
   return random.choice(list_of_cars)

@MemoryClass
def SelectFreeAccessories(list_of_cars):
    return random.choice(list_of_cars)

print("Promotion: ", SelectTodaysPromotion(cars))
print("Show: ", SelectTodaysShow(cars))
print("Free accessories: ", SelectFreeAccessories(cars))
```

Now I just don't understand.  If I declare `function` as a parameter of `__init__`, does Python relate it straight away to the type `function` or could it be any object/variable just called "function"?

Similarly, if I declare `list` as a parameter of `__call__`, does Python relate it to type `list` or could it be any object/variable just named "list"?

Thanks a lot for clarification, it is not explained well in my course and I want to get it.
~xoxo

Comment: Variable names are just that: names.  Any type enforcement you desire you have to implement yourself (or you can follow the "let it crash" philosophy).  What you can do is add [type hints](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/) to your code to let the user know what types they *should* be using.  On a related note, `function` and `list` are [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).  You shouldn't use them as variable names.

Comment: Useful link by [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) about names in python.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that using such variables names is slightly confusing ...  I guess I will note it for the author of this tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Parameter names are just that: *names*, unrelated to anything else.

That said, a parameter name is an implicit assignment. When the function is called, a local name is created in the scope of the function, assigned whatever argument is provided to the call. That local name can shadow any other name in the global or built-in scopes.

`function` isn't a name in the built-in scope (the way to get access to the built-in `function` *type* is through the module global `types.FunctionType`, so nothing is shadowed by a parameter named `function`. (Unless you defined one in the global scope yourself, which you did not here.)

`list`, however, *is* a name defined in the built-in scope, bound to the built-in type. So you if you have a parameter named `list`, you lose access to the built-in name for the duration of the function call. This is why it is *recommended* to not shadow built-in names, though you never truly lose access: you can always import the `builtins` module and use `builtins.list`:

```
import builtins


list = 3
list()  # TypeError, 'int' object is not callable
builtins.list()  # Creates a new empty list.
```